# Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider ClassNotFoundException when trying to build an Android Plugin for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-fileprovider, androidx

I am trying to build an android plugin for unity3d that simply share a screenshot to another app via the FileProvider.
I migrated my project to androidx.
I have used androidx.core.content.FileProvider class.
My app crashes whenever I launch it, with the following Logcat:

```
2018-12-22 21:46:13.678 14755-14755/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.anascompany.testandroidplugin, PID: 14755
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.anascompany.testandroidplugin-bwZMktz2HTL449ojsD7y9g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:121)
```

I have searched about the problem and tried the following:
1. MultiDex problem.
In order to include MultiDex easily in my project I changed the minimum SDK to API 23 Marshmallow 6.0.
Where the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) said that to include MultiDex you need to add `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig in the build.gradle file for the specified module.
Note: the documentation said that this is the only step required to include MultiDex if the minimum SDK is set to API 21 or higher.
2. wrong package problem (I guess that's the problem).
prior to androidx we used this package: `com.android.support:support-v4` so according to this [page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings) you should replace the previous package with: `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` and also replaced `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider` with `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`.
here is my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anascompany.unity">
<application>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.anascompany.unity.fileprovider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

and here is my build.gradle file for my module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}

task copyPlugin(type: Copy){
    dependsOn assemble
    from ('build/outputs/aar')
    into ('../../Assets/Plugins/Android')
    include (project.name + '-release.aar')
}
```

Note: the target SDK is both in unity and android studio set to 28 "Android Pie".
Note: my question is different from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624510/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-support-v4-content-fileprovid) because I have already included in the manifest `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" after androidx migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624510/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-support-v4-content-fileprovid)

Comment: @AlexKolydas No it's not duplicate because I have avoided that question mistake (and that's clear from my android manifest).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to implement `androidx.core:core:1.10-alpha02` in your build.gradle.

Comment: @Hks.Adohkd it's 1.1.0

Comment: @TheWanderer Sadly my friend I tried that too, with no hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, it´s so so simple. As simple as copy manually "support-v4-24.1.1.aar" into the plugin unity project folder. Or other support aar android file. It comes with the SDK.
In my case the file was in "C:\AndroidSDK\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\24.1.1"

No matter the version but you should be sure that "FileProvider" class is inside the file. You can unzip the aar file simplily with winrar and be sure that the class is in there.

---UPDATED---

In summary: inside /yourProjectFolder/Assets/Plugins copy your unity-release.aar compiled android module and manually too the support-v4-24.1.1.aar (or other versión, the size of mine is near 1MB)

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.unity">
<application>
 <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.unity.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
 </provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And here my module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I hope it helps you and other.

Comment: didn't work for me too, are you sure you haven't changed anything in the manifest or the build.gradle for this library? could please check these files and confirm that they are the same as mine? if not please update your answer.

Comment: Oh yes! I touch everything to made this works but finally works that. Oh yes... I had see you use androidx... First I used this but finally I made the plugin again from the beginning using support v4. It is possible that if you put androidx on manifest and put android support in the plugin directory it will be the same mess no? Maybe I could help you follow up my answer with my manifest and the dependencies ok?

Comment: Ok please update your answer, by showing your manifest and the build.gradle files so I can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I was out working hard. You already have my answer updated

Answer (score 3):

Change to

> implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, your answer didn't work for me too

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the newer implementation (androidx.core.content.FileProvider) and it still crashes you might as well need to put the library manually into the project.

I downloaded the aar file (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.core/core/1.0.1) and since i was working on a unity3d project i put it into the folder "Assets\Plugins\Android\libs". For Android it might be "Android\lib".

Hope it was helpful for someone

Comment: This helped me get androidx support lib working with Unity.

Comment: I did these and this was not the correction for me.
I believe it has to do with an asset in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same initialization error. I changed the Code Shrinker property in Android Project Property from ProGuard and R8 to EMPTY. This solved the issue. Just remove the ProGuard property and it works. I will try to find another workaround later but for now, this is fine with me.

Comment: I did these and this was not the correction for me.