# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/AppComponentFactory

Tags: android, androidx, activeandroid

Was working on very old project whose target and compile sdk version was 21, now i upgraded to 29 and move to androidX i resolved most of the things in project and working fine on some devices but stuck on below mentioned error in some of the devieces in the line **ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);** after searching i got many links like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026021/classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-graphics-drawable-drawablewrapper), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266035/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-appcomponentfactory-in-package-and), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624510/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-support-v4-content-fileprovid) but none of these links helped my problem.
ActiveAndroid library causing the problem as per my understanding
So please any one here in community able to help me out please let me know the solution for this.
My log is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/AppComponentFactory;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getParsers(ReflectionUtils.java:158)
        at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:100)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
        at com.mouchel.mobile.application.MouchelMobileApplication.onCreate(MouchelMobileApplication.java:169)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5844)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1708)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.AppComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mouchel.mobile--MCfu3k3U7lgApGDfwJjeg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mouchel.mobile--MCfu3k3U7lgApGDfwJjeg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.mouchel.mobile--MCfu3k3U7lgApGDfwJjeg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

and the gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"


sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "-----"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "-----"
        property "sonar.host.url", "-----"
        property "sonar.language", "-----"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/"
        property "sonar.login", "-----"
        property "sonar.password", "-----"
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "-----"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled = true
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }




dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /* compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')*/
    implementation files('libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/asmack-android-4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')

    implementation files('libs/SiiAndroidSDK.jar')

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    // Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added

Comment: @user121190, what was your solution?

Comment: @gotwo i upgraded the activeandroid beta library.